# Make Square The Tallest Cell of Every Row of Table Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

[image]

In HTML `<table>`

Using Javascript, i want to make square (or nearly square) the tallest cell (having max no. of lines) in every row, which results in decreasing rows height and make table compact.

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/okoer70u/ . See unnecessary white-space in ROWS, if we add `white-space:nowrap` to table then columns will have extra white-space.

All my tables are wider than screen and totally different cells text length and no. of cells so i can't use css like `width` `min-width` etc.

fyi, I am not using jquery.
 What about wrapping the text inside the cells in a div. then count characters to find biggest?

please help

Comment: Please post your code here instead of relying on external links -- or at the very least, in addition to.

Comment: A fiddle is always nice, but please do include the code here as well. External sites may not be around for ever or be accessible for everyone.

Comment: Since it is a layout thing, you could consider including an image here instead of the code.

Comment: your points are acceptable, i will include soon...

Comment: I don't know how you could find the tallest cell in a row, since all of them will always have the same height. Would it be OK to wrap the text inside the cells in a `div` like this: `<td><div>Text.</div></td>`? Also, are you using jQuery or any other library, or does it have to be vanilla JS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85229/discussion-between-anders-and-feacco).

Comment: it would be okay to wrap and not using jquery.